# how to find largest letter (A-Z) in a range which also contain some blank cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel sheet, I wanted to find the largest letter in a range raw-wise. Some cells in the range are blank cells. I tried the below formula but it didn't work for me. Please help me to solve this out

```
=CHAR(AGGREGATE(15,6,CODE(A1:A10),1))
```

[image: Screenshot of execel]

Thanks!

Comment: Excel or Googlesheets? Please select which is relevant.

Comment: this site has some ideas on alphabetic sorting as well using formulas like: =INDEX(A2:A8,MATCH(MIN(COUNTIF(A2:A8,”<”&A2:A8)),COUNTIF(A2:A8,”<”&A2:A8),0))

https://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/finding-the-maximal-minimal-string-based-on-alphabetic-order.html

Comment: Try `ARRAY FORMULA` if you are using `GS`, and please use proper hash tags! Check in answers, provided solution for both kind of spreadsheets, though both looks same but functionality differs!

Answer (score 1):

Try using anyone of the either

```
=CHAR(AGGREGATE(14,6,CODE(B3:L3),1))
```

[image: MICROSOFT_EXCEL]

**AGGREGATE** doesn't work in google sheets

Try ARRAY FORMULA With LARGE Function

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CHAR(LARGE(IFERROR(CODE(A2:K2);"");1)))
```

[image: GOOGLE_SHEET]

Comment: This is worked to me. 
=CHAR(AGGREGATE(14,6,CODE(B3:L3),1))

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=index(sort(transpose(split(regexreplace((TEXTJOIN("",,A2:K2)),"(.)","|$1"),"|")),1,0),1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. 
but it's given me an error

Invalid Name Error
The formula contains unrecognized text.

Comment: this is a google sheet formula

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `M3`:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(B3:K)&"|"&B3:K),"|"),"Select Max(Col2) group by Col1 label Max(Col2) ''"))
```

A single array formula that will spill results down. Also, it would now no longer matter if the largest value is also the latest. Put an 'X' down under 'EI-1` in the 1st row and it will be your latest version.

See a sample [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cdqz1wiAwmtdO9goQJHNt5DUstuSUgnyrMikRHzxJM8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, I have edited the answer to include a link to the sample. Also, how I make them? Can you be more specific what you want to learn?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, the point is that it's an arrayformula with spilling results. Don't drag the formula down. I resolved it for you in the linked sheet. As per the "I want to learn from you", I guess it's mostly experience in understanding what functions do. Keep tabs on answer on SO to see what other users come up with =)

Comment: Thank You, Sir, You and Scott Craner sir are always in top priority and bookmarked, !!!